# How to Use WorksheetFunction.Vlookup to copy data from different worksheets and list common variables

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

```
Sub Packaging_run_dropbox_change(ColRef As Integer)
On Error Resume Next

'Created by Marc Hipolito on 26/10/2021

'# This subroutine is a slave routine used by all
'# Packaging run dropbox routines

'# Variables
Dim BP As Worksheet         '# Bottling Programme
Dim Ip As Worksheet         '# Input worksheet
Dim Ref As Worksheet        '# Ref worksheet
Dim ptr As Integer          '# Pointer
Dim BottleSKU As Integer    '# Bottle SKU
Dim BPBottleType As String  '# Comment from bottling programme
Dim i As Integer            '# pointer

'# Set worksheet objects
Set BP = Worksheets("Bottling Programme")
Set Ref = Worksheets("Ref")

'# Use dropdown box selection number as pointer
ptr = Ref.Range("L" & ColRef + 1)

'# Find Bottle SKU according to Bottle Type
BottleSKU = Ip.Cells(2, 6)

'Set Input as prod run input
Set Ip = Worksheets("DepalBottles")
   
'# Display SKU according to bottle type from batch number
Ip.Range("C2") = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Ip.Cells(2, 6), Ref.Range("A2:C20"), 3, False)

'# Display Material Number according to SKU
Ip.Range("D2") = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Ip.Cells(2, 6), Ref.Range("A2:C20"), 2, False)
```

Basically it is doing what i need it to do but what I want is that if it has a common name to list it together in Ip.Range C2.
For example Burg F/G appears twice but only returns 17521, but theres another Burg F/G which is 17522. Can it appear that it will show on Ip.Range C2 "17521/17522"?

Any help would be appreciated. Maybe not a Vlookup? Maybe a Match Index?
This is my table in a Ref sheet

[image: Ref sheet]
[DepalBottles Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ue8O.png)

Comment: Welcome!  Check out how to include a [mcve] with your question. Also helpful is "[ask]".  Adding more information would make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Try using `Filter` based on your criteria and then build your string based on filtered range